# Using POUND SIGN as a string in PYTHON?

Tags: python

I want to have a string containing 4 pound signs..how can I accomplish this in Python without commenting the string out due to the pound signs?

Comment: Do you mean a `#` or a `£` sign?

Comment: Did you try rodrigo's solution before posting? If not, why not?

Comment: Does not work in the Nuke IDE

Comment: If some IDE interprets '####' as a half-baked string plus a comment, change the IDE!

Answer (score 13):

What about:

```
x = '####'
```

If between quotes, it will not be a comment!

Answer (score 2):

If some IDE interprets '####' as a half-baked string plus a comment, change the IDE!

Answer (score 1):

As said before, single quotes do the job for string literals. You might also want to have a look at [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html)